# How to run Mocha test on browser written in Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, mocha.js

I'm new to `NodeJS` and `TypeScript`.
So, I'm stuck little bit now.

My project configs are like this.

```
+------------+---------------------------+
|            |          purpose          |
+------------+---------------------------+
| Webpack    | create a bundle JS file   |
| TypeScript | ES5 transpile             |
| Mocha      | TDD test                  |
+------------+---------------------------+
```

I'm trying to run `Mocha` test code written in `TypeScript`.
And this test is using `XMLHttpRequest` module.

My project structure is like below.

```
|_ dist (for bundle file)
|_ script
|   \_ lib
|       \_ ajax.ts (my module)
\_ test
    \_ script
        \_ lib
            \_ ajax.spec.ts (to test my module)
```

I figured out that `XMLHttpRequest` module is for a browser. 
And I can replace this for installing npm module `xmlhttprequest`. 
But, I need to check if response has received and callback function has executed.

After run my test, I succeed to open request, but cannot get any response and call back function has not executed. 
So, I decided to test `XMLHttpRequest` module on a browser.

Luckily, I found a tutorial for [running Mocha Tests in a browser](https://medium.com/dailyjs/running-mocha-tests-as-native-es6-modules-in-a-browser-882373f2ecb0).
But, my problem is that my `Mocha` code is written in `TypeScript`.

So I think my process for testing would be like below.

> 1. Compile `ajax.spec.ts` which compiled out as `ajax.js` and `ajax.spec.js`.
> 2. Make one `JS` bundle file for `ajax.js` and `ajax.spec.js` using `Webpack`.
> 3. Make a `html` like tutorial above.
> 4. Open `html` and check my test result.

Am I alright? Should I make a bundle for compiled files? 
Is there a sample or tutorial for **running `Mocha` tests written in `TypeScript` on a browser**?

Thank you.